# How to calculate the sum of each column on merging two data frames without specify the column name

Tags: r

I have two data frames as below:

```
> d1
  v x y
1 X 1 5
2 X 2 6
3 X 3 7
4 X 4 8
> d2
  v x y
1 X 1 5
2 X 2 6
3 X 3 7
4 X 4 8
```

I want to merge them and sum each `x` and `y`. Below command works fine for me:

```
> ddply(merge(d1,d2, all=TRUE), .(v), summarise, x=sum(x), y=sum(y))
  v  x  y
1 X 10 26
```

In above command, I have to specify the column name for `x` and `y`. I am looking for a way to calculate the sum value with specifying each column name. Because I have a data frame which includes more than twenty columns, I don't want to specify each of them. Is there an automatical way for me to calculate all columns?

Comment: In your example since `d1` and `d1` are identical the `merge` isn't doing anything, but assuming it does what you want, you could use `library(dplyr); full_join(d1, d2) %>% group_by(v) %>% summarise_all(sum)`

Comment: your command works fine. But I figured our an easier way: `d1[2:3] + d2[2:3]` returns the similar result if I don't care about the column `v`. Is it correct?

Comment: It won't aggregate by `v` value and you'd need to do `colSums` to collapse the columns, but for the example data yes.